# Refreshing views after a non-graphical event

Tags: cocoa

I am currently making a Cocoa network client, that should modify some NSViews and NSTableViews whenever it gets some messages from its network connection.

Whenever it gets messages from the connection, it does eveything fine, except refreshing the views.
I tried `[tableView reloadData]` for the NSTableView without effect.
I tried `[view setNeedsDisplay:YES]`, `[view setNeedsDisplayInRect:]`, `[itsSuperView setNeedsDisplay:]`, but none of them is working.

The objects view and tableView are correctly linked with IB though, since calling `reloadData` or `setNeedsDisplay` when the user clicks on a button works fine.
It looks like `setNeedsDisplay` or `reloadData` are useless when not called from a method triggered by the GUI...

Do you have any hint ? It's been a couple of days I'm having this problem without finding any suitable solution...
Thanks

--Edit : here is the code

```
@implementation myWindowController
- (id)init{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"ListWindow"]; //Form ListWindow.xib
    return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{   [super windowDidLoad];
}


//From button in the GUI
- (IBAction)refresh:(id)sender{
    [tableProcessus reloadData];    //Actually refreshes the tableView
}


//Form network
- (void)handleIncomingText:(NSString *)str{    
    if([str isEqualToString:@"add an item"]){
        [glob addItem:3];           //glob is a custom array
        [tableProcessus reloadData];    //Does nothing visible (doesn't even trigger numberOfRowsInTableView:)
    }
}


#pragma mark tableProcessus Data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView{
    return [glob numberOfItems];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex{
    return [glob itemAtIndex:rowIndex];
}

@end
```

Comment: The object that receives the messages has an outlet to the table view? Are you using a background thread?

Comment: Actually, I'm sending the `reloadData` message directly to the table view. And from the main thread (where `[NSThread isMainThread]`return `YES`)...

Comment: Which object is sending `reloadData`? The network message receiver? Some other controller? Is that the same object that sends `reloadData` when the button is pressed? Does that object own the network message receiver? What I am asking is, what's the relationship between that message receiver object and the `reloadData` call?

Comment: I have a MyWindowController, which is the delegate class of my network receiver. Whenever a message arrives, it is routed to MyWindowController, that parses it, modifies a couple of arrays, and then sends `[myTableView reloadData]`, whose content should change according to these arrays.

In myWindowController, I have `IBOutlet NSTableView *myTableView`, along with `-(IBAction)clic:(id)sender` (which sends `[myTableView reloadData]` as well).

Yet, when the reloadData message is sent from -clic:, it correctly updates its view, but not when it is sent after myWindowController parses the message.

Comment: Okay, I think you'll have to post the code that leads up to the failing `reloadData` call. Also, how is the table view getting its data? Bindings or data source? If data source, which object implements those methods?

Comment: The table view is getting its data from myViewController, as a data source. The code of myViewController is in the last edit of my initial question. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Thanks. Okay, forgive me for asking this, but you've verified that the `if` succeeds sometimes, right? Also, when you checked `isMainThread`, were you _inside the body_ of `handleIncomingText:`? Other than those two things, if the `IBAction` works, I'm personally stumped.

Comment: Thanks a million for your help guys. But I eventually spotted the problem. I instantiated myWindowController like a newbie, and there were 2 instances of myWindowController at runtime : one that received GUI events, and the other that received network events. I changed quite a few things with IB, and my program now works very well... Thanks very much anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `setNeedsDisplay:` on the main thread?
If not, you should do that: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH12-123427

Comment: As George Sachin posted, you could use performSelectorOnMainThread:.  Can you post that should trigger the update?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use 
`performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`

Thats because only the main thread can change the NSView view. SetNeedsDisplay etc wont work. On the main thread you have to write a method that changes the view, and call it using a selector.

Here is a link to the method: [performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a)

Comment: Unfortunately, network events are already handled in the main thread (my WindowController is the network's delegate, and `[NSThread isMainThread]`returns `YES`)... I tried what you suggested all the same, but it didn't help :-/